# correlated outputs in neural network

Tags: neural-network, coordinates

I have a data set (containing some inputs and one output and GPS coordinates show the location of each sample) and I need to predict output with a neural network (NN). But the problem is that each element of output vector is correlated with other elements according to the place they are measured in that close samples tend to be more similar than distant samples and so the distances between the samples are important. Is there any way to add this extra information into NN structure?

Comment: Neural networks act like a black blox: they will figure out these correlations. Have you tried running and training a network yet?

Comment: I've trained (with back-prop algorithm) an MLP using GPS coordinates as input (along with the others), but the results are not good enough. I'm looking for other structures for NN or other training algorithms.